# How do I read a file object into parallel arrays (2D string and 1D int)?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, file, parallel-arrays

Trying to make a Spanish-English dictionary. I'm writing strings (for the words) and ints (for a "times word searched" feature) into a file, reading them into parallel arrays, and displaying those arrays to make sure they're reading correctly.

File data reads into arrays and prints to console fine, except when it breaks out of the `for` loops, it evaluates `!EOF` as still true and repeats the `while` loop one more time.

This is what the code looks like now:

```
// GLOBAL CONSTS
const int ENG_WORDS = 3, SPN_WORDS = 2, SIZE = 3;

// MAIN
    string words[ENG_WORDS][SPN_WORDS]; int searches[SIZE];
    ofstream outFile; ifstream inFile;

    // FILE WRITE
    outFile.open("test.txt");
    outFile << "hello, hola, 0" << endl <<
                "bye, adios, 0" << endl <<
                "thanks, gracias, 0" << endl;
    outFile.close();

    // FILE READ
    inFile.open("test.txt");
    while (!inFile.eof())
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < ENG_WORDS; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < SPN_WORDS; c++)
            {
                inFile >> words[r][c];
                cout << words[r][c] << " ";
                if (words[r][c] == words[r][SPN_WORDS - 1])
                {
                    inFile >> searches[r];
                    cout << searches[r] << "\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    inFile.close();
```

Output:

```
hello, hola, 0
bye, adios, 0
thanks, gracias, 0
hello, hola, 0
bye, adios, 0
thanks, gracias, 0
```

This is the mess I had before attempting to debug:

```
    // FILE READ
    inFile.open("test.txt");
        while (!inFile.eof()) {
            for (int r = 0; r < ENG_WORDS; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < SPN_WORDS; c++)
                {
                    inFile >> words[r][c];
                    cout << words[r][c] << " ";
                    if (words[r][c] == words[r][SPN_WORDS])
                    {
                        inFile >> searches[r];
                        cout << searches[r] << endl;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Output when `ENG_WORDS = 3, SPN_WORDS = 3`:

```
hello, hola, 0 bye, adios, 0 thanks, gracias, 0 hello, hola, 0 bye, adios, 0 thanks, gracias, 0
```

Output when `ENG_WORDS = 3, SPN_WORDS = 2`:

```
hello, hola, 0 bye, adios, 0 thanks, gracias, 0 bye, adios, 0
```

Output when `ENG_WORDS = 2, SPN_WORDS = 2`:

```
0, bye, adios, 0 0 (infinite loop)
```

I assumed EOF was evaluating to true because the row size was too small to hold all of the rows in the file. While the output was more or less in the right order, it was actually overwriting the array before. (Array singular, since the `if` was just being skipped over and the 3x3 string array was holding the 0s.) Funnily enough, when `ENG_WORDS = 3` and `SPN_WORDS = 2`, it only repeats the second row, instead of all three.

Also, if I put `\n` in the file write, the file never reads into the array but always executes the `if` statement, displaying garbage values in `searches[r]`. This is why I'm using `endl`, but if there's a way around that I'd love to know.

Comment: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons) Always test if the input is successful and act accordingly. Checking for eof like that is like trying to predict the future. The last read didn't trigger it but the next might and you'll be handling bad data until the next eof check.

Comment: Unless you MUST use parallel arrays, consider using a structure that aggregates the data in the two arrays and one array of that structure.

Comment: *"when it breaks out of the `for` loops, it evaluates `!EOF` as still true"* -- Why do you think it should be false?

Comment: You might also consider reading a full line and then parsing that line with a `stringstream`.

Comment: SO Usage Note: You're almost always better off with a [mre], but try to provide code that people can run without having to make changes or guesses to fill in blanks. This lets people out here drop your code into their tools, experiment with it, and test possible solutions against it.

Comment: The simpler and more abstract your question, the better for the site. Instead of reading a dictionary, what happens if you simply try to read words? Keep the first two levels of your looping structure, have maybe two words to read (I'd say one, but two justifies a loop), then demonstrate that EOF has not been reached. (This is for the "minimal" part of "[mre]".)

Comment: How come your Spanish-English dictionary can have different numbers of Spanish and English words? Why are you using a 2D array at all. Why not three parallel 1D arrays? It's clear that the code does not work but it's hard to know what you are trying to do, so it's hard to suggest a fix. And as already stated above, `eof` does not work in the way you think it does, just forget about `eof`.

Comment: Here's is one way to read the file correctly `std::string eng, spa; int num; while (inFile >> eng >> spa >> num) { ... }`. Now you cal fill in the `...` part to put the words and numbers into whatever arrays you want.

Comment: parallel arrays are almost never a good idea. Declare a struct `struct dictionary_index_t { std::string spanish_word; std::uint64_t search_count; }` and then you can make a std::unordered_map<std::string,dictionary_index_t> dictionary` to organize your data.